# How to configure nginx for 2 react + express app

Tags: reactjs, express, ubuntu, nginx

i've been struggling to configure the sites-available config file and was hoping to get some guidance. I'm trying to point sub.domain.com/app1 and sub.domain.com/app2 to the correct location. I have 2 react and express running on port 2000 and port 3000, and they are both working file when accessing the ip address and port number (xx.xx.xx.x:2000). One of the app works if the location is root(/), but as soon as I try to change the location or add another the page turns blank. Any help would be appreciated.

> server {
> listen 80;
> server_name sub.domain.com;
>
> ```
> location /app1 {
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
>     proxy_http_version 1.1;
>     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
>     proxy_set_header Host $host;
>     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_buffering off;
>     proxy_request_buffering off;
>     proxy_cache_revalidate on;
> }
>
> location /app2 {
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
>     proxy_http_version 1.1;
>     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
>     proxy_set_header Host $host;
>     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>     proxy_buffering off;
>     proxy_request_buffering off;
>     proxy_cache_revalidate on;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a standard react application(not a next.js one) then you will need to first build it and then you have to place it in the correct path, as example `/var/www/html/app1/`

So your `default.conf` would include the following:

```
 location /app1 {
    alias /var/www/html/app1/;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }


  location /app2 {
    alias /var/www/html/app2/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
  }
```

Now, if you run CRA then you should have a look on [their deployment guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/), especially in *Serving the Same Build from Different Paths*

Comment: Ahh I see. Is it best to build it as opposed to running it on a port and using something like pm2 for the front and back end? I did try this method once but I ran into an issue with make trying to make a request to an endpoint. I'll definitely try this again and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @mnguyen20 This is how it has to be done, as you want to have a production ready build, if you had a issue with endpoints then it has to be resolved on backend/devops side. 
Its a little different on next.js but I believe you dont use that .

Comment: I see! I just went ahead and configured the default.conf file and it seems to be pointing correctly, but I ran into another issue. So my app works just fine at the root level "/" but whenever I point it to a subdirectory of "/app1" the page turns white and I receive a bunch of errors in the console. Is this due to how I have my pathing structured on the client and server? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @mnguyen20 as mentioned in original answer, you need to check CRA deployment guide(if u use CRA, that is).  Most likely you are missing *homepage* in package.json. If the originl answer helped you, please marked it as answered

Comment: Looks like I was missing the homepage in the package.json, like you said. Thanks a bunch! I got all of the client side working, just have a lot issues with the server and nginx configuration. Thanks again.